# How to customize Symfony 3.4 collection prototype

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I know I'm not the first who's asking this question. But I tried everything to get it working.

At first, I have a entity named `Assignment` and another entity `unit`. `Assignment` has a manyToMany relation to `Unit` called `units`.

This creates the form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pickupTime', DateTimeType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Zeitpunkt Abholung',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
        ])
        ->add('deliverTime', DateTimeType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Zeitpunkt Lieferung (geplant)',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
        ])
        ->add('customer', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Kunde',
            'class' => Customer::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('cu')
                    ->leftJoin('cu.client', 'c')
                    ->where('c.id = :cid')
                    ->setParameter('cid', $options['client_id'])
                    ->orderBy('cu.companyName', 'DESC');
            },
        ])
        ->add('pickupAddress', AddressType::class, [])
        ->add('deliverAddress', AddressType::class, [])
        ->add('units', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => UnitType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'assignment-units',
            ),
        ]);
}
```

And here's the template for the form part of `units`:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                {{ form_label(form.units) }}
                <table class="table table-bordered table-light collection-form-wrapper">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Bez.</th>
                        <th>Stück</th>
                        <th>Gewicht</th>
                        <th>Breite</th>
                        <th>Höhe</th>
                        <th>Tiefe</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for unit in form.units %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form_row(unit.name) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form_row(unit.pieces) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form_row(unit.weight) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form_row(unit.width) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form_row(unit.height) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form_row(unit.depth) }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete" data-id="{{ loop.index }}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% else %}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" class="text-center">
                                <div class="p2">
                                    <i>
                                        <small>Noch keine Einträge vorhanden</small>
                                    </i>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="7">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="add-item"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                Hinzufügen</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete-all"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Tabelle leeren</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _units_entry_widget %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.name) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.pieces) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.weight) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.width) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.height) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.depth) }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete"><i
                        class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't work - it correspondents to the symfony docs (http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype) - but I get the error message `Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "name()", "getname()"/"isname()"/"hasname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".`.

What's wrong with me? I don't understand where's the problem. When I try to override the widget of `units` with form_theme, the debugger show no fields of the collection `units`. When I delete the part with the form_theme, the fields are shown.

EDIT:
Code of UnitType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('quantity')
        ->add('weight')
        ->add('width')
        ->add('height')
        ->add('depth');
}
```

Comment: I think that the error comes from `form_row(unit.name)`. Did you define a `name` field in `UnitType`? Could you please add the code of `UnitType` in your question?

Comment: I also tried it with `form_row(unit.name)`, then the error is `Variable 'unit' does not exists.`. I've added the code in the questen.

Comment: I have the same error if I follow the Symfony document word by word. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the name of the *block* you use to customize the collection's items view.

The first part must be the **parent form name**.

The second part the **collection field name**.

The third part must always be **_entry_row**.

So (depending on the name of your forms) you should write something like:

`{% block _assignment_units_entry_row %}` instead of {% block _units_entry_widget %}